# Proof by induction - algorithm

Tags: algorithms, solution-verification, induction, recursive-algorithms

I need some help to sort out if my answer is right for this question. The algorithm calculates $x^n$.

Question: Argue the correctness of the algorithm using proof by induction.

Note: Even if you haven't managed to complete the previous proof, assume that expIterative(x, n) has been proven to be correct for any x ∈ R and n >= 0. Furthermore, remember that integer divison always rounds off toward 0, and consider the two cases when n is odd and when n is even. A proof by induction is most appropriate for this algorithm.

```
double expRecursive(double x, int n) {
    if (n <= 4) {
        return expIterativ(x, n);
    }

    return expRecursive(x, n/2) *
           expRecursive(x, (n + 1)/2);
}
```

My answer:

Base Case:

We can from the note assume that it works for $n = 4$.

Inductive case:

Assume that is works for n = k: $expRecursive(x, \frac{k}{2}) \times expRecursive(x, \frac{k+1}{2}) = x^k$

Than show that it also works for $n = k + 1$:

FOR ODD N:

$expRecursive(x, \frac{k+1}{2}) \times expRecursive(x, \frac{k+2}{2}) = expRecursive(x, \frac{k+1}{2}) \times expRecursive(x, \frac{k+1}{2}) = x^{\frac{k+1}{2}} \times x^{\frac{k+1}{2}} = x^{k+1}$

FOR EVEN N:

$expRecursive(x, \frac{k+1}{2}) \times expRecursive(x, \frac{k+2}{2}) = expRecursive(x, \frac{k}{2}) \times expRecursive(x, \frac{k+2}{2}) = x^{\frac{k}{2}} \times x^{\frac{k+2}{2}} = x^{k+1}$

Is this the correct way to do it or how should I do it?

Comment: Off-topic: in some languages, using recursion in this way would leak to Stack Overflow error.  You might want to do the calculations within the recursive function arguments.  It's better to replace in by an iterative function in practice.

Comment: Does your code try to multiply `expRecursive(x, n/2)` with `expRecursive(x, (n+1)/2)`?

Comment: The question is in a textbook without answers and not my own code :)

Comment: Yes, it multiplies expRecursive(x, n/2) with expRecursive(x, (n+1)/2)

Comment: This algo gives $O(\log n)$ (for $n = 2^m$, it generates $2^{m-2}+2^{m-3}+\dots++2^2+2+1 = 2^{m-1}-1$.  Draw a tree diagram to see this.) recursive calls.  That easily leads to Stack Overflow error for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct.  The if-else statement

```
if (n <= 4) {
    return expIterativ(x, n);
}
```

corresponds to the base case.

The induction hypothesis has been correctly stated.

The inductive step

```
return expRecursive(x, n/2) 
       expRecursive(x, (n + 1)/2);
```

is based on dividing $n=k+1$ into two cases according to its parity.  The logic in your proof is good.

Remarks: It's likely that you've omitted a `*` in your code.

```
return expRecursive(x, n/2) * expRecursive(x, (n + 1)/2);
```